# Extjs grid with multiselect feature to retrieve value of selected lists

Tags: forms, extjs, grid, multi-select

Let's say I have a grid with multiselect option on, when user selects 4 lists and wants to get the values ( alerted on screen) how would I do that? And how would I disable buttons untill at least one list is selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All questions you've asked are answered many times already. Also there are [good ExtJS examples](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) on sencha.com. For example [list view grid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/list-view.html) shows multiple select and [editable grid with writable store](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/writer/writer.html) shows button enable on click. But **THE MOST** important is [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#)! Let me explain functionality on following code. Most of it is from `list view` example.

This grid gets JSON from `list.php` which has following structure

```
{"authors":[{"surname":"Autho1"},{"surname":"Autho2"}]}
```

And the grid:

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.panel.*'
]);
Ext.onReady(function(){
    // Here i've definned simple model with just one field
    Ext.define('ImageModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['surname']
    });
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'ImageModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'list.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'authors'
            }
        }
    });
    store.load();

    var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: 'myPanel', // Notice unique ID of panel
        width:425,
        height:250,
        collapsible:true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        store: store,
        multiSelect: true,
        viewConfig: {
            emptyText: 'No authors to display'
        },

        columns: [{
            text: 'File',
            flex: 50,
            // dataIndex means which field from model to load in column
            dataIndex: 'surname' 
        }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            // This button will log to console authors surname who are selected
            // (show via firebug or in chrome js console for example)
            text: 'Show selected',
            handler: function() {
                // Notice that i'm using getCmp(unique Id of my panel) 
                // to get panel regerence. I could also use 
                // this.up('toolbar').up('myPanel')
                // see documentation for up() meaning
                var selection = Ext.getCmp('myPanel').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                for (var i=0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                    console.log(selection[i].data.surname);
                }
            }
        },{
            text: 'Disabled btn',
            id: 'myHiddenBtn', // Notice unique ID of my button
            disabled: true // disabled by default
        }]
    }]
    });

    // Here i'm waiting for event which is fired
    // by grid panel automatically when you click on 
    // any item of grid panel. Then I lookup
    // my button via unique ID and set 'disabled' property to false
    listView.on('itemclick', function(view, nodes){
        Ext.getCmp('myHiddenBtn').setDisabled(false);
    });
});
```

I didn't knew how to do this from top of my head, but I used documentation and the result works ;-). See [Grid panel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel) docs for more information.

Comment: this was a solution, you are awesome :)